# Python won't load images from CSS

Tags: html, python-3.x, css

New to coding, but have been learning python with some ease. recently have been toward the final stages of page development, but images from CSS aren't loading via python correctly.

## PY Code

```
    from flask import Flask, render_template


    app = Flask(__name__)


    @app.route('/')
    def home():
    return render_template ('Sign_up.HTML')


    if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## HTML Code (line referencing css)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/style.css" />
```

## CSS Code (where images are present)

```
    body
    {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        background-image: URL(C:/project/img/bkg.png) ;
        background-size:  100%;
        font-size: 16px;
        color: #274FA6;
        font-family:  sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

    #login-box
    {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        margin: 5% auto;
        width:800px;
        right:2px;
        height: 500px;
        background-image: URL(C:/project/img/LoginBox.png);
        background-size: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0.6);
```

It all worked fine when just running the HTML in chrome, and as far as I can tell, the rest of the CSS works fine, the images just aren't loading now when I run it through python. I have included the path to the images in the environment. I have changed the location of the images to the static folder and changed the directory to find them, along with making the URL as specific as possible, but with no success. Thanks to anyone who can help out!